# How to show an image in the intersection between two polygons?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, html5-canvas

I have an idea for an effect that I'm trying to code with Javascript and html5 Canvas, but I'm not sure exactly where to start.

Say you have multiple different colored polygons (let's say Rectangles for now but ideally pseudo-random irregular polygons). You can move the polygons around by clicking and dragging.

When you drag one of the polygons over another polygon, I'd like to show an image in the intersected area. Imagine dragging a blue polygon over a red polygon to create an area of purple, except instead of purple it's a leopard print pattern, or a photo, or similar.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Finding the intersection between objects is a non-trivial task

Answer (score 1):

Using the 2d context clip function. Draw the shape as normal then draw them again but instead of fill use clip after each shape.

Each clip is applied to the previous clip.

When all the clips shapes have been set then draw the image/shape over the top and only the parts inside the clip area will show.

To remove the clip you need to use save and restore (see demo);

Using code from another example I just wrote, being a bit lazy.

Example shows the union of 3 boxes as blue using the clip functionality of 2D context.

```js
/** SimpleUpdate.js begin **/
// short cut vars 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
ctx.font = "18px arial";
var cw = w / 2;  // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var angle = 0;
var focused = false;
var rotated = false;

// Handle all key input
const keys = {  // key input object
    ArrowLeft : false,  // only add key names you want to listen to
    ArrowRight : false,
    keyEvent (event) {
        if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {  // are we interested in this key
            keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
            rotated = true; // to turn off help
        }
    }
}
// add key listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", keys.keyEvent)
document.addEventListener("keyup", keys.keyEvent)

// check if focus click
canvas.addEventListener("click",()=>focused = true);

// main update function
function update (timer) {
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // reset transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);      
    
    // draw outside box
    ctx.fillStyle = "red"
    ctx.fillRect(50, 50, w - 100, h - 100);
    
    // rotate if input
    angle += keys.ArrowLeft ? -0.1 : 0;
    angle += keys.ArrowRight ? 0.1 : 0;
    
    // set orgin to center of canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
    
    // rotate
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    
    // draw rotated box
    ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
    ctx.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
    
    // set transform to center
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
    // rotate
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    // move to corner
    ctx.translate(50,50);
    // rotate once more, Doubles the rotation
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
    ctx.fillRect(-40, -40,80, 80);

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default
    



    // set up the clip area
    ctx.save();  // save the non cliped canvas state
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(50, 50, w - 100, h - 100);
    ctx.clip(); // clip main box

    // set orgin to center of canvas
    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);    
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
    ctx.clip(); // add to clip (reduces area

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(50,50);
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(-40, -40,80, 80);    
    ctx.clip();

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);  // restore default
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    
    ctx.restore();  // this removes the clip. It is the only way to remove it
                    // apart from reseting the context
    
    
    
    ctx.fillStyle = "white"
    ctx.lineWidth = 3;
    if(!focused){
        ctx.strokeText("Click on canvas to get focus.",10,20);
        ctx.fillText("Click on canvas to get focus.",10,20);
    }else if(!rotated){
        ctx.strokeText("Left right arrow to rotate.",10,20);
        ctx.fillText("Left right arrow to rotate.",10,20);
    }else{
        ctx.strokeText("Blue is the union of the...",10,20);
        ctx.fillText("Blue is the union of the...",10,20);
        ctx.strokeText("...yellow, black, and red boxes.",10,h-5);
        ctx.fillText("...yellow, black, and red boxes.",10,h-5);
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);


/** SimpleUpdate.js end **/
```

```html
<canvas id = canvas></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ones that don't like clipping (like me), you can also achieve it with compositing.

Basically, you'd need to draw your shapes twice : once on the visible canvas, and once on an hidden one, used only to create the intersection area.

Draw the first shape with normal compositing mode `'source-over'`.
Then, draw all your shapes with the compositing mode `'source-in'`. This will keep only the new pixels which overlaps previously drawn ones.

When you're done drawing your shapes, only the intersection part should remain on this hidden canvas. So still with this composition mode, you can draw your image, the size of the canvas. Your image will be clipped.

As I am lazy too, I shamelessly took Blindman67's code*, and didn't even bothered to rewrite it in a more elegant way to avoid boilerplate, while it should probably be done.

```js
/** SimpleUpdate.js begin **/
// short cut vars 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
// create an hidden canvas' context
var ctx1 = canvas.cloneNode().getContext('2d');
var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;
ctx.font = "18px arial";
var cw = w / 2; // center 
var ch = h / 2;
var angle = 0;
var focused = false;
var rotated = false;
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/100px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg';


// Handle all key input
const keys = { // key input object
  ArrowLeft: false, // only add key names you want to listen to
  ArrowRight: false,
  keyEvent(event) {
    if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) { // are we interested in this key
      keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
      rotated = true; // to turn off help
    }
  }
}
// add key listeners
document.addEventListener("keydown", keys.keyEvent)
document.addEventListener("keyup", keys.keyEvent)

// check if focus click
canvas.addEventListener("click", () => focused = true);

// main update function
function update(timer) {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset transform
  ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  ctx1.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  // draw outside box
  ctx.fillStyle = "red"
  ctx.fillRect(50, 50, w - 100, h - 100);
  // reset default compositing mode
  ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
  // and draw the first shape
  ctx1.fillRect(50, 50, w - 100, h - 100);
  // now we will keep only the new pixels which overlap with existing ones
  ctx1.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-in';
  // rotate if input
  angle += keys.ArrowLeft ? -0.1 : 0;
  angle += keys.ArrowRight ? 0.1 : 0;

  // set origin to center of canvas
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
  // apply all the same transforms to the hidden canvas
  ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
  // rotate
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx1.rotate(angle);
  // draw rotated box
  ctx.fillStyle = "Black"
  ctx.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);
  ctx1.fillRect(-50, -50, 100, 100);

  // set transform to center
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
  ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, cw, ch);
  // rotate
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx1.rotate(angle);
  // move to corner
  ctx.translate(50, 50);
  ctx1.translate(50, 50);
  // rotate once more, Doubles the rotation
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx1.rotate(angle);

  ctx.fillStyle = "yellow"
  ctx.fillRect(-40, -40, 80, 80);
  ctx1.fillRect(-40, -40, 80, 80);

  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore default
  ctx1.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

  // our hidden canvas only contains the overlapping of all our shapes
  // we can draw our image on this intersection area
  ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0, w, h);
  // and draw this back on the main canvas
  ctx.drawImage(ctx1.canvas, 0, 0);

  ctx.fillStyle = "white"
  ctx.lineWidth = 3;
  if (!focused) {
    ctx.strokeText("Click on canvas to get focus.", 10, 20);
    ctx.fillText("Click on canvas to get focus.", 10, 20);
  } else if (!rotated) {
    ctx.strokeText("Left right arrow to rotate.", 10, 20);
    ctx.fillText("Left right arrow to rotate.", 10, 20);
  } else {
    ctx.strokeText("Image is the union of the...", 10, 20);
    ctx.fillText("Image is the union of the...", 10, 20);
    ctx.strokeText("...yellow, black, and red boxes.", 10, h - 5);
    ctx.fillText("...yellow, black, and red boxes.", 10, h - 5);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(update);

}
requestAnimationFrame(update);


/** SimpleUpdate.js end **/
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

*I hope he won't mind, and if he does, he just has to let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little simpler with SVG.  :)

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 500">
  <defs>
    <circle id="left" cx="250" cy="250" r="250"/>
    <circle id="right" cx="550" cy="250" r="250"/>
    <mask id="intersect">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      <use xlink:href="#right" fill="white" mask="url(#maskleft)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="maskleft">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      <use xlink:href="#left" fill="white"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#left" fill="red"/>
  <use xlink:href="#right" fill="blue"/>
  <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-500-500-8.jpg"
         x="280" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#intersect)"/>
</svg>
```

**Animated version**

```js
var start = null;
var maskleftcircle = document.getElementById("maskleftcircle");
var puppygroup = document.getElementById("puppygroup");

function step(timestamp) {
  if (!start) start = timestamp;
  var angle = ((timestamp - start)/250) % 360;

  var dx = 100 * Math.cos(angle);
  var dy = -100 * Math.sin(angle);

  puppygroup.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+dx+","+dy+")");
  maskleftcircle.setAttribute("transform", "translate("+(-dx)+","+(-dy)+")");

  window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 500">
  <defs>
    <circle id="left" cx="250" cy="250" r="250"/>
    <circle id="right" cx="550" cy="250" r="250"/>
    <mask id="intersect">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      <use xlink:href="#right" fill="white" mask="url(#maskleft)"/>
    </mask>
    <mask id="maskleft">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black"/>
      <use xlink:href="#left" fill="white" id="maskleftcircle"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#left" fill="red"/>
  <g id="puppygroup">
    <use xlink:href="#right" fill="blue"/>
    <image xlink:href="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-500-500-8.jpg"
           x="300" y="0" width="500" height="500" mask="url(#intersect)"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Except when you need to make all these shapes dynamically move/appear/disappear ;-)

Comment: I didn't say impossible ;-) Just not as simple as it may seem from your snippet. Canvas code would also be simpler for the exact same result as yours. (Ps: no libs allowed for this challenge :-D )

Comment: Tada! Still quite small. :)